# Rectangle in pygame won move consistently

Tags: python, pygame

I thought that this code would cause a rectangle to move when a key is pressed and cause it to stop moving when the key is released but I must be missing something. Can anyone see what's wrong with this code? I'm trying it to make a rectangle move when I hold the key and stop when I release it like in pong.

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()

WINDOWWIDTH = 600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (0, 0, 255)
FPS = 40
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
rectY1 = 300
rectY2 = 300
Y1change = 0
Y2change = 0
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

def moveup():
    rectY1 -= 10
pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')
def drawshapes():
    pygame.init()
    DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((600,600),0,32)
    DISPLAY.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,RED,(18,rectY1,10,120))
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,RED,(580,rectY2,10,120))
    pygame.draw.ellipse(DISPLAY,BLUE,(300,300,30,30))
drawshapes()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                Y1change -= 10

            elif (event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
                Y1change += 10

            elif (event.key == ord('w')):
                Y2change -= 10

            elif (event.key == ord('s')):
                Y2change += 10             
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if (event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                Y1change = 0

            elif (event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
                Y1change = 0

            elif (event.key == ord('w')):
                Y2change = 0

            elif (event.key == ord('s')):
                Y2change = 0

    rectY1 += Y1change
    rectY2 += Y2change
    drawshapes()
    pygame.display.update()






    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need Pygame events for this sort of continuous movement, just use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` which returns a dictionary of keys currently pressed.

In the example code below, I wrapped a PyGame Rect rectangle object into another class.  This allows the "Paddle" to maintain location data, and know how to draw itself to the screen.

Please try this example.

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

DARK_BLUE = (   3,   5,  54 )
YELLOW    = ( 255, 250, 205 )

PADDLE_WIDTH = 70
PADDLE_HEIGHT= 10

### initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Moveable Rectangle")


### Simple class to hold the position of a moveable rectangle
### and keep it on-screen.
class Paddle:
    def __init__( self, x, y, width, height ):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect( x, y, width, height )

    def draw( self, window ):
        """ Draw the paddle on the given surface """
        pygame.draw.rect( window, YELLOW, self.rect, 0 )  # filled rectangle

    def move( self, x_delta ):
        """ adjust the position of the paddle by <x_delta> pixels """
        # Change position
        self.rect.x += x_delta
        # Keep it on the screen
        if ( self.rect.x < 0 ):
            self.rect.x = 0
        elif ( self.rect.x + self.rect.width > WINDOW_WIDTH ):
            self.rect.x = WINDOW_WIDTH - self.rect.width



### Controls
# Create a paddle, roughly centred in the window
player_paddle = Paddle( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT-50, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT )

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
        player_paddle.move( -10 )
    if ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
        player_paddle.move( 10 )

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( DARK_BLUE )
    player_paddle.draw( window )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

You are getting pressed keys and storing them as `keys`, but you're not actually using them anywhere.

Further down, you are detecting key down and up events, but I've noticed that immediately after a key down event, pygame will generate a key up event, even if the key hasn't been released, so that's why you only see a small move.

Comment: So how would i fix it?

Comment: Good question - I cut out some of your code, but I consistently see the same behaviour you do, a keyup right after a keydown. I'll play around some more - often it's best to start with a minimal example and see if that does work as expected.

Comment: Stripping down the code to just opening a window and detecting keys, it appears that events in `pygame` aren't very reliable and you're probably better off following the advice of others and looking at the status of currently pressed keys.